# Doctoral symposium after graduation

Tags: publications, phd

A few months ago I submitted my work to a doctoral symposium. At that moment I was PhD student and the work was accepted.

Now I am just graduated and my question is if I should still attend the doctoral symposium as graduated instead of as student.
Moreover, I have checked the conference schedule and it has a slot for me.

What is the best way to handled this situation?

Comment: Did you contact the organizers?

Comment: Not yet. I'd like to have advices of what to do.

Comment: Well, the only reasonable answer we can give is to 'ask the organizers'. I don't know what a doctoral symposium is, but it surely has some rules...

Answer (score 2):

As multiple comments have suggested, contacting the organizers appears the appropriate option. Although the symposium is strictly titled 'doctoral symposium', the organizers may be more interested in allowing you to **showcase your work** and to **practice your presentation/dissemination skills** (I am guessing it is for the latter).

But, will you be physically and financially capable of attending the meeting?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The funding is other issue, though.

Comment: If you don't have the funding now and there's a good chance you won't get it, contact the organizers. Sometimes they can waive registration for volunteering, or out of pity. Also, the sooner you let them know you can't make it the lower the chance you have of burning that bridge.